# How can I convert multiple iso date format with the same function to date in java?

Tags: java

I am creating a DSL with ANTLR 4, and I wonder if it is possible to convert several date format (string) to date with the same function without passing the format for example if my DSL is like that

```
date1 = "2020-05-08"
date2 = "2020/05/08"
date3 = "20200508"
...
```

and in my java code I convert the string directly to date without knowing the format for example

```
Date date1 = convertToDate(date1);
Date date2 = convertToDate(date2);
Date date1 = convertToDate(date3);
```

instead of writing

```
Date date1 = convertToDate(date1,"yyyy-mm-dd");
Date date2 = convertToDate(date2,"yyyy/mm/dd");
Date date1 = convertToDate(date3,"yyyymmdd");
```

Comment: Why dont you check the format type in your convertToDate method ? That way you can call it as you want

Comment: No, it's not possible. How would the program differentiate if `20` is `dd` or part of `yyyy`?

Comment: Also, why are you using so much outdated `java.util.Date`? Check [this](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to learn about modern date/time API.

Comment: You can remove all symbols and just use the convertToDate(date3,"yyyymmdd");

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash _"No, it's not possible."_ That's incorrect. Refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61688949/1426227) for an approach to achieve that.

Comment: @cassiomolin - Your answer is great but given OP's requirement to do `Date date1 = convertToDate(date1)`, my comment holds true. OP wanted to pass just date string as the parameter and nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Java 8, which introduced the new [Date and Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), you are no longer advised to use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and so on. Those are now *legacy* types.

Also, if you intend to parse the month, you are supposed to use `MM` instead of `mm` (which indicates minutes).

With the new Date and Time API, you could use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with **optional patterns** using `[` and `]`. Then you can parse the string dates to [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) instances, as shown below:

```java
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd]")
        .appendPattern("[yyyy/MM/dd]")
        .appendPattern("[yyyyMMdd]")
        .toFormatter();

LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("2020-05-08", dateFormatter);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("2020/05/08", dateFormatter);
LocalDate date3 = LocalDate.parse("20200508", dateFormatter);

System.out.println(date1);
System.out.println(date2);
System.out.println(date3);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've passed you can remove all non digit symbols to use only one convert function. Ex:

```
date1 = "2020-05-08"
date2 = "2020/05/08"
date3 = "20200508"
...

dateN = removeSymbols(dateN);

Date date = convertToDate(dateN,"yyyymmdd");
```

To remove the non digit you can use this function:

```
dateN = dateN.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Comment: yes, but if the client writes `date = 10-05-2020` then I should change the format to `dd-mm-yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy`. I would like to develop a generic solution but it seems to me that it's impossible.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to accomplish this with a simple regex.

```java
Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile("^(?<Year>\\d{4})[/-]?(?<Month>\\d{2})[/-]?(?<Day>\\d{2})$")
```

Then build the date with the match groups.

Comment: I wouldn't use regular expressions for parsing dates. That's what `DateTimeFormatter` is meant for.